# Merge multiple MsgBox into one

Tags: vba, msgbox

I am trying to merge multiple MsgBoxs into one, but i have no luck.
If you have any ideea, please help. This is my VBA:

```
  If Worksheets("XXX").Range("D13") > 0 Then

MsgBox ("ATENTION!" & vbCrLf & "OLD = ") & Worksheets("XXX").Range("D13") & " PCS !"
End If

If Worksheets("XXX").Range("E13") > 0 Then
MsgBox ("ATENTION!" & vbCrLf & "REQUEST = ") & Worksheets("XXX").Range("E13") & " PCS !"
End If
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show both messages in one box? Like this?

```
Dim msg As String
If Worksheets("XXX").Range("D13") > 0 Then
    msg = "ATENTION!" & vbCrLf & "OLD = " & Worksheets("XXX").Range("D13") & " PCS !"
End If

If Worksheets("XXX").Range("E13") > 0 Then
    msg = msg & vbCrLf & "ATENTION!" & vbCrLf & "REQUEST = " & Worksheets("XXX").Range("E13") & " PCS !"
End If
MsgBox msg
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: One more question please: if even if XXX!D13 =0, i still recieve an empty message with "ok" button. How can i change the vba, so that in case XXX!D13 is zero, not to have any message.

Comment: I added this line to the vba, but now it seems more complicated :) If msg <> "" Then MsgBox msg.      Now, the message won't appear at all, if D13=0 and E13=1

Comment: @lofgren This is the best solution you can use. If this is complicated code for you, then you have never seen complicated code ;)

Comment: I just discovered VBAs two monts ago, so yes, some things are complicated... :))